# jQuery toggleClass not working in my example

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

ToggleClass seems to not do anything on my site and i can't figure out why.
I wrote a short example to make it easier for me but it still doesn't work...
I think I got the syntax right...

http://jsfiddle.net/eakzrqqg/

```
<!--html-->

<div class="arrow">
    <a href=#>menu<br>▼</a>
</div>

<ul class="header-links">
        <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link3</a></li>    
</ul>

<!--css-->

.bg{
       background: black;  
    }

<!--js-->

$(".arrow a").click(

function () {
$(".header-links").toggleClass(".bg");
}

);
```

Comment: It's `$(elem).toggleClass("bg")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".header-links").toggleClass("bg"); //Just remove '.' in 'bg' class name here.
```

Comment: I have another question now... The example above worked but when I tried to modify the height of the element on click, it didn't work anymore... http://jsfiddle.net/eakzrqqg/2/

Comment: @user3211838...sorry but i m not fully understanding your problem..if it is possible for you then plz post a question and then explain what you want actually...

Comment: I wanted to show some hidden links (initially with height:0) when i click on "menu". Clicking should make the height 100 or something so that the links can be seen.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Only I wanted to use toggleClass.